# HangFire Recurring job at 3 given times

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have set a recurring job to run at this time but i would like to repeat it at 2 more specific times. How can i do it?

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TerminaTurnos>(t => t.Termina(),  Cron.Daily(22, 10), TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just create 3 reccuring jobs (executing the same job) to execute on different times giving the jobId parameter for each of them:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TerminaTurnos>("job1", t => t.Termina(),  Cron.Daily(18, 10), TimeZoneInfo.Local);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TerminaTurnos>("job2", t => t.Termina(),  Cron.Daily(20, 10), TimeZoneInfo.Local);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TerminaTurnos>("job3", t => t.Termina(),  Cron.Daily(22, 10), TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

**EDIT:**

But you can also make one reccuring job with cron expression like:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TerminaTurnos>(t => t.Termina(), "10 18,20,22 * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

It will execute the job `at minute 10 past hour 18, 20, and 22.`

Comment: Ah i see, i thought i had to give it 3 cron expressions on the same one somehow

Comment: @Jackal you can also create one reccuring job with a cron expression. I edited my answer.

Comment: What is the difference from the 2nd option?

Comment: The difference is that you create one reccuring job only.