# how to pause hangfire's job? between certain hours

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I want have hangfire jobs not working if the time is between 8:00 pm & 8:00 am between these hours I wanna hangfire jobs idle. any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HangFire Recurring job at 3 given times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568418/hangfire-recurring-job-at-3-given-times)

Comment: Are you talking about background jobs or recurring jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a correct cron expression to the recurring job which will fire your desired code.

For example, this cron expression runs the job every hour from 8AM to 8PM.

```
0 0 8-20 ? * * *
```

Cron is a "whitelist" approach (i.e. when to work) than "blacklist" approach as in your questions (when not to work). Hangfire runs recurring jobs based on cron expressions.